# HttpWebRequest + Windows Auth - NetworkCredential just doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web service. On my dev box, I'm running IIS Express 7.5, so we're calling localhost:port. I have set it to use Windows Authentication and switched off Anonymous.

On my client, if I set

```
HttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

it works. But if I set the credentials to my other Windows domain account,

```
HttpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("lpuplett", "catsGoW00f", "ntdom"));
```

then I get a 401 Unauthorized. Am I misunderstanding something; should this work?

I've tried adding the credentials to a CredentialCache object and setting the cache.

Comment: I guess this is not duplicate. I pointed posts asks for windows authentication  and the answer in that post uses Ntlm… I am also facing same issue using windows authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From comment in linked duplicate question:

> You need to specify the authentication type. When the server
>   challenges the client with NTLM authentication the
>   ICredentials.GetCredential method will be called on
>   WebClient.Credentials with authType = "NTLM". If you used
>   WebClient.Credential = new NetworkCredential(...) as no authentication
>   type is specified the client won't be able to respond correctly.
>   CredentialCache already implements this functionality. – Darin
>   Dimitrov Nov 5 '09 at 14:57